# Expo hanging at "Starting Metro Bundler" and "Waiting on http://localhost:19000"?

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler, turborepo

I saw ['expo start' or 'npm start' command stuck at ''Starting metro bundler"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66290059/expo-start-or-npm-start-command-stuck-at-starting-metro-bundler) and pretty much ever SO and GitHub question about this issue, but I am not seeing any debug info to go off of and figure this out.

```
$ pnpm dev

> @ dev /Users/lancepollard/start/tunebond/deck/term.land
> turbo dev

• Packages in scope: dock, tsconfig, view, web
• Running dev in 4 packages
• Remote caching enabled
web:dev: cache bypass, force executing 7c3c8e5e3e5b4eb4
dock:dev: cache bypass, force executing 70a3664db71da2bc
view:dev: cache bypass, force executing 18cd9e0579e13849
dock:dev:
dock:dev: > dock@1.0.0 dev /Users/lancepollard/start/tunebond/deck/term.land/site/dock
dock:dev: > pnpm start
dock:dev:
web:dev:
web:dev: > web@1.0.0 dev /Users/lancepollard/start/tunebond/deck/term.land/site/link
web:dev: > next dev
web:dev:
view:dev:
view:dev: > view@0.0.0 dev /Users/lancepollard/start/tunebond/deck/term.land/tool/view
view:dev: > tsup --watch
view:dev:
view:dev: CLI Building entry: {"index":"src/index.tsx"}
view:dev: CLI Using tsconfig: tsconfig.json
view:dev: CLI tsup v6.0.1
view:dev: CLI Using tsup config: /Users/lancepollard/start/tunebond/deck/term.land/tool/view/tsup.config.ts
view:dev: CLI Running in watch mode
view:dev: CLI Target: node14
view:dev: CLI Cleaning output folder
view:dev: CJS Build start
view:dev: ESM Build start
view:dev: CJS ⚡️ Build success in 5ms
view:dev: ESM ⚡️ Build success in 5ms
view:dev: CJS dist/index.js 2.01 KB
view:dev: ESM dist/index.mjs 685.00 B
view:dev: CLI Watching for changes in "."
view:dev: CLI Ignoring changes in "**/{.git,node_modules}/**" | "dist"
web:dev: - ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
dock:dev:
dock:dev: > dock@1.0.0 start /Users/lancepollard/start/tunebond/deck/term.land/site/dock
dock:dev: > expo start
dock:dev:
view:dev: DTS Build start
dock:dev: Starting project at /Users/lancepollard/start/tunebond/deck/term.land/site/dock
view:dev: DTS ⚡️ Build success in 560ms
web:dev: - event compiled client and server successfully in 574 ms (311 modules)
web:dev: - wait compiling...
web:dev: - event compiled client and server successfully in 182 ms (311 modules)
dock:dev: Starting Metro Bundler
dock:dev: Waiting on http://localhost:19000
dock:dev: Logs for your project will appear below.
```

I basically installed [this](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/with-react-native-web) sample project and have been working through getting it going. Some issues I fixed:

- [Removed the `dev` resolver](https://superuser.com/questions/1413402/i-cant-visit-websites-that-have-dev-domain/1413487#1413487) locally so `api.expo.dev` would resolve.
- Increased the per-process descriptor limit with `sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=10485760` and `sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=1048576`
- Updated to the latest `expo-cli` (6.3.8)
- Updated to the latest `expo` node module (48.0.19)

So with all that I got here, but it just sits there at the `Starting Metro Bundler` step. What else could be going wrong? How can I get it working? I tried connecting from my iPhone hotspot vs. my home router, but same issue in both spaces.

If I `cd` into the nested folder where the react-native / expo project actually is (inside this "turbo" monorepo), it seems to work?

```
$ cd site/dock
$ pnpm start

> dock@1.0.0 start /Users/lancepollard/start/tunebond/deck/term.land/site/dock
> expo start

Starting project at /Users/lancepollard/start/tunebond/deck/term.land/site/dock
Starting Metro Bundler
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▀▄█▀  █  █ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
..........cut out..........
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄█▄▄█▄█▄█▄█▄▄█▄▄█

› Metro waiting on exp://172.20.10.4:19000
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

› Press a │ open Android
› Press i │ open iOS simulator
› Press w │ open web

› Press j │ open debugger
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
```

Why wouldn't the turbo version be working? How can I go about debugging this better perhaps, and get around the issue with it just stalling. I also tried `npx expo start --tunnel` and it still hanged.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the npx expo install @expo/webpack-config@^18.0.1

and run with npx expo start --tunnel

Press w │ open web